# Regex OR stop matching at the first word

Tags: javascript, regex

Here are the data I receive :

I want to get only  the message of the question. It is possible that my question is on several lines. For that I put "/s" at the end of my regex.

My regex is : `/question : ((.|)*)\n?(line_1|line_2)/s`

Example 1:

```
question : this is my question
line_1: 0
line_2: 1
```

Example 2 :

```
question : this is my question
line_2: 1
```

For my example 2 it's ok it works but for example 1 the condition "or" does not stop at the first occurrence found, do you have a solution ? Thanks for your help

Comment: @meropis  JavaScript tag could well be useful, regEx do have slight differences depending on language used.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, going to do some reading! Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Keith Regex variants are radically different, I wouldn't call the differences "slight"

Comment: @mousetail  Yeah, slight might be an under statement, but radical might be an over statement..   Maybe I should have said "there are differences.."

Comment: Drop this awful `((.|)*)\n?` and would match lines optionally (without the `s` flag), eg like this: [`question : (.*(?:\nline_[12].+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/627Oxp/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
question\s*:\s*(\S.*(?:\r?\n.+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ASeZMh/1). Note I added `\r?` because the `.` in JavaScript does not match carriage returns.

If `line_1` and `line_2` are `line_` + digits and must be present, then include them as

```
question\s*:\s*(\S.*(?:\r?\nline_\d.*)*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ASeZMh/2).

*Details*:

- `question` - a word
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(\S.*(?:\r?\nline_\d.*)*)` - Group 1:

  - `\S` - a non-whitespace char
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\r?\nline_\d.*)*` - zero or more lines that start with `line_` and a digit and then the rest of the line can have any chars. `(?:\r?\n.+)*` matches any zero or more non-empty (zero-length) lines.

Comment: @Thomas Then use the first `question\s*:\s*(\S.*(?:\r?\n.+)*)` regex. Or add the words using a non-capturing group, e.g. `question\s*:\s*(\S.*(?:\r?\n(?:word1|word2).*)*)`

Comment: I have another problem when the message has a line break everything that follows is not taken in the regex, just the first line.

If I put in options /s it does not stop at my word1 or 2. @wiktor-stribiżew

Comment: @Thomas Please share a [regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/ASeZMh/3), please update this one to show what exact problem you have, and explain where the match should end and why. Or, what the match must consist of.

Comment: I found a solution sorry for the inconvenience, it's ok now. I do : `question\s*:\s*(.*?)(?:word1|word2)` and use "m" and "s". Thanks for you help

Comment: @Thomas Glad you found a solution for the real problem. I could only answer what you asked.